# How to rename dates in multiple file names

Tags: bash, filenames, rename

I have files that look like this:

```
ABC_20210101.csv
ABC_20210101_imp.csv
```

I would like to update the dates in the file name to a specific date:

```
ABC_20201231.csv
ABC_20201231_imp.csv
```

How can I go about replacing these file names?

Comment: Is it always `ABC_` then eight digits to be replaced, then the trailer?

Comment: It could be anything really. For instance it could be ABC_DEF_20210101.csv

Only thing that is constant is that it will either be yyyymmdd.csv or yyyymmdd_imp.csv

Comment: So it's _anything_, then eight digits that need to be replaced, then  either `_imp.csv` or `.csv`

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel:

```
ls | parallel mv {} '{= s/(.*)\d{8}/${1}20210131/ =}'
```

Tested on:

```
this_123456789_file_19991231_some.thing
```

You can include GNU Parallel directly in the script, if you do not have permission to install software on the system you will be running on:

```
parallel --embed > newscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` you can split the filenames apart and reassemble them

```
#!/bin/bash
new="20201231"

for file in *.csv
do
    # Split the filename into its consituent parts
    if [[ "$a" =~ (.*)[0-9]{8}(_imp)?(\.csv)$ ]]
    then
        # Assemble a new filename
        dest="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${new}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        if [[ ! -f "$dest" ]]
        then
            # No destination so rename
            [[ -t 2 ]] && echo "Rename $file as $dest" >&2
            echo mv -f "$file" "$dest"    # Remove "echo" to action
        fi
    fi
done
```

This is much easier with `rename` but not all systems have it installed (remove `-n` or replace with `-v` to action):

```
new="20201231" rename -n 's/(.*)?[0-9]{8}(_imp)?(\.csv)$/$1$ENV{new}$2$3/' *.csv
```

If you don't have `bash` or `rename` then `sed` can be used to generate the necessary target filename. Arguably this is easier code to read (apart from the RE, which has many backslash escapes to satisfy `sed`'s ERE handling)

```
new="20201231"

for file in *.csv
do
    # Generate new filename
    dest=$(
        printf "%s\n" "$file" |
        sed -n 's/\(.*\)[0-9]\{8\}\(_imp\)\{0,1\}\(\.csv\)$/\1---\2\3/p'
    )

    if [ -n "$dest" ] && [ ! -f "$dest" ]
    then
        # Pattern substitued and target does not exist so rename
        [[ -t 2 ]] && echo "Rename $file as $dest" >&2
        echo mv -f "$file" "$dest"    # Remove "echo" to action
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to rename the files isvto first select the files using find utility abd then pass them onto sed which will construct the new name and tgen pass a pair to xargs to call mv command to do the renaming.

```
d0=19710110
d8=$(seq -f '[0-9%g]' 8 | paste -sd'\0')
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*_${d8}_imp.csv" -o -name "*_$d8.csv" \) -print |
sed -Ee "h;/_[0-9]{8}((_imp)?[.]csv)\$/s//_$d0\1/;x;G" |
xargs -r -d'\n' -n2 -t mv -i
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard POSIX `sh` shell  allows us to write patterns like

```
./*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv
```

and

```
./*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_imp.csv
```

These would match the files you're interested in, in the current directory. (You could make these more specific, obviously, like `./*20[0-2][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9].csv`, which would still allow for matching invalid dates.)  Then names matching these patterns could then be renamed like so:

```bsh
for name in ./*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv
do
    [ ! -e "$name" ] && continue
    newname=${name%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv}20201231.csv
    mv "$name" "$newname"
done

for name in ./*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_imp.csv
do
    [ ! -e "$name" ] && continue
    newname=${name%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_imp.csv}20201231_imp.csv
    mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```

The `${variable%pattern}` substitution removes the string that matches `pattern` from the end of the value `$variable`.